# WinLogon.exe process not starting LogonUI.exe in Windows 7

Tags: windows, boot

I'm trying to debug a Windows 7 machine which is not starting Windows. The Windows loading animation plays, the screen goes black, and the cursor appears in the center. I can move the cursor around, but nothing else happens.

The Secure Authentication Sequence (Ctrl-Alt-Delete) does nothing. There is no welcome screen, no account ever seems to get loaded. Safe Mode does not work either, behaves the same way as normal mode.

I've attached a kernel debugger via the 1394 port and WinDbg on my host is working fine. I can analyze the running processes/threads on the target during the black screen.

I found a great article describing the Windows 7 start-up process here: http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/windows-7-startup.htm

SMSS.exe, CSRSS.exe, WinInit.exe, LSASS.exe, LSM.exe all seem to be loaded.

WinLogon is also loaded. It's supposed to start the LogonUI.exe process, but it never does. According to the article, WinLogon is supposed to load the UXinit.dll, but it never does. I can find this module loaded on other PC's i have, but according to WinDbg it is never loaded in WinLogon on my target machine.

I have checked the stacktrace of all threads (~4) inside WinLogon during the black screen, and there doesn't seem to be anything hanging. The thread that seems to be the "main" thread seems to loop at a function called WaitForLSMStart forever, which i thought was the problem, but LSM.exe is loaded and I noticed this loop running inside WinLogon on other active machines i have running. I believe this has something to do with terminal services?

It seems to me like something is going wrong inside Winlogon that prevents it from starting the LogonUI process, and I can't figure out what.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to repair the Windows installation? If that doesn't work, you might have to reinstall Windows.

Comment: Yes, tried repairing a long time ago.

I'm mainly interested in figuring out what is actually going on. I might end up disassembling winlogon.exe and figuring out how it works. I was hoping maybe someone already had this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the Winlogon configuration that is at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` and compare it to a working system. Specifically, there's `UIHost` value that shall link to `logonui.exe` and `Notify` subkey that lists other DLLs loaded at certain times.

If the entries are correct, `logonui.exe` or some DLL that it depends on may be corrupt.

ERD commander (now it's called MsDaRT) can help you explore the offline system and may be able to fix this (it has a wizard to "automatically fix startup problems" with unspecified functionality).

Comment: @Matviy so, did you identify the culprit?